# Stress test a WPF application to find threading issues

Tags: c#, wpf, task-parallel-library, stress-testing

How to stress test a WPF application which uses TPL? Are there any automated tools available ?

Comment: can you give more detail on what you're looking for?  Places that incorrectly write to the UI on the wrong thread?  Places that do too much work on the UI thread and block it for longer than X milliseconds?  Something else?

Comment: @JamesManning Exactly ,also possible deadlocks ,data corruption by two threads entering the critical section etc.I just watched watched the video CHESS: An Automated Concurrency Testing Tool.So I was wondering if there is any such utility or tools available for WPF

Comment: I don't know of any similar tool targeting WPF, but the source appears to be able to work against managed code fine.  The UI-specific threading issues seem less likely to get tested, but those tend to fail pretty quickly at runtime anyway.  http://chesstool.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For writing the stress tests you could use [White](http://white.codeplex.com/) to write your automated ui tests and then run them but not sure of any tools that will automatically stress test your application.

A better way to think of it is to stress test say an API function/service endpoint I guess and use something like osherove thread tester to spin up the threads easily

for monitoring the performance of the stress test I think you should check out this

http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/

I think it is free to dowload and trial for 30 days, it does a lot of what you ask for, you can see what is happening on what thread, how long each task and subtask is taking, it renders this out quite nicely as well.

I think jetbrains has an equivalent which is pretty much feature equivalent.

If you can't fix your problem in the 30 days trial with redgate you then just download the jetbrains one and use that 30 days as well.

Good luck

Comment: RockThunder, The idea about the White seems to interesting,I do have a licensed version of Ants perfomance profiler ,though i would prefer the concurrency visualizer better particularly when working with tasks.  Can you please provide more info on osherove thread tester ?